# Most computationally efficient way to classify the comparison two numpy arrays of 1s and 0s; if an index of both contains 1s, or 0s, etc

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two numpy arrays

```
prediction = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
groundtrue = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

I would like to compare the two arrays, including a classification of each index comparison. So I want to classify if both `prediction` and `groundtrue` have 1s, or if `prediction` has 1 and `groundtrue` has 0, or vise versa, etc.

So an example desired result could look like this

`comparison = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1])`

1 is used if both have 1s. 2 is used if both have 0s. 3 is used if if `prediction` has 0 and `groundtrue` has 1. etc.

The most straight forward way is to use a loop and directly compare each index but it seems that numpy may have some operators that can do this very computationally efficiently and much less lines of code

`np.where(prediction == groundtrue, 1, 0)`

Can get me an array where the two values are equal, or not, but I don't see it giving different types of comparisons.

Comment: `prediction + 2 * groundtrue` will give a classification, might not be the order you wanted though.

Comment: This solves my answer. You can submit this as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only 0s and 1s in `prediction` and `groundtrue`, there will be only 4 cases in total. Hence you can create a classification with:

```
prediction + 2 * groundtrue
# array([3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3])
```

It won't be the same order as in OP, but enough to distinguish different cases.

- 0 if both `prediction` and `groudtrue` are 0s;
- 1 if `groudtrue` is 0 and `prediction` is 1;
- 2 if `groudtrue` is 1 and `prediction` is 0;
- 3 if both are 1s;

Answer (score 1):

One can do this with boolean masks.

```py
import numpy as np

prediction = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
groundtrue = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

comparison = np.zeros_like(prediction)
comparison[(prediction==1) & (groundtrue==1)] = 1
comparison[(prediction==0) & (groundtrue==0)] = 2
comparison[(prediction==0) & (groundtrue==1)] = 3
comparison[(prediction==1) & (groundtrue==0)] = 4
comparison  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1])
```

The following gives the same output as the above, but you only need to compute two masks. This assumes that prediction and ground truth can only have values of 0 or 1.

```py
import numpy as np

prediction = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
groundtrue = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

pred0 = prediction == 0
ground0 = groundtrue == 0
comparison = np.zeros_like(prediction)
comparison[~pred0 & ~ground0] = 1
comparison[pred0 & ground0] = 2
comparison[pred0 & ~ground0] = 3
comparison[~pred0 & ground0] = 4
comparison  # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1])
```

---

The masks will have boolean values, where each value indicates whether the condition is true in the original array.

```py
x = np.array([0, 1])
x == 0  # array([ True, False])
```

The `&` operator will compute the logical AND of both boolean arrays. See [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) for more information.

Then, one can use the boolean mask to subset certain values. We can assign that subset of indices a new value.

```py
x = np.array([0, 1])
x[x==0] = 2
x  # array([2, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using code like this:

```
import numpy as np
prediction = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
groundtrue = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
lut=np.array([2,4,3,1]) #look up table
pow_two=2**np.arange(2)
comparison=lut[np.dot(pow_two, np.vstack((prediction, groundtrue)))]
```